# Slack-socketmode Custom integration

Tags: slack

Can we post message(alerts) to slack through custom integration using slack socket mode. We do have slack inbuilt webhooks to post message to slack but due to some reasons it is restricted in my environment.

Expected result - Mechanism to post message to slack channel using Slack socket mode without using slack inbuilt incoming webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Socket Mode, then you could use [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) instead of webhooks to deliver messages.